# How do I bridge Android guest network traffic?

Tags: networking, android-emulator

I need a way to direct all traffic from an ARM Android guest to a virtual bridge on the host.

I'm using the Android emulator binaries (built from source) and Android images built from the AOSP repository.

What I have tried:

- Starting the emulator with qemu parameters to create a NIC and connect it to a host bridge (`my-interface`) gives a `Segmentation Fault`.

  ```
  emulator -avd [...] -qemu -net nic -net tap,ifname=my-interface
  ```
- Disabling the `adbd` service inside the guest did not solve the above.

From what I understand, the system uses the default interface (`eth0`, which is a default qemu user mode interface) for adb, which *might* be why I cannot replace it with a TAP interface.

Is there a way I can work around this?

Comment: you can see my answer to this post: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/191004/how-to-use-net-tap-with-android-sdk-emulator/191743#191743 and some resulting issues that I have found: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/191522/connect-android-emulator-to-lan