# How to use -net-tap with android sdk emulator?

Tags: networking, android-sdk, development

I am trying to create a bridge between android emulator (from android sdk) and host system using -net-tap. Is there any working manual for that case? I have tried to launch emulator with `-net-tap tap0` - `tap0` appeared in host system, but no one interfaces appeared in guest android. I also tried 
`-qemu -net tap,iface=tap1,script=no`, but it also doesn't work. I checked `/proc/kmsg`, there are no anything connected with new interface.

Full cmdline looks like `/opt/android-sdk/emulator -avd test-x86 -accel off -no-audio -net-tap tap0 -qemu -net tap,ifname=tap1,script=no`

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: `-net-tap tap0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think -net tap is the old way, use -netdev tap with new android sdk emulator and -device virtio-net-pci for x86 android emulator. For ARM emulator you must use an other device.

And you must install the emulator package with the sdkmanager as this:

```
sdkmanager emulator
```

Then you can use the emulator located in /opt/android-sdk/emulator/emulator.

Create a network bridge which include a tap interface (tap0) for the emulator and an ethernet interface (enp0s20u1) connected to a lan network.

```
# ip addr flush dev enp0s20u1
# ip link set enp0s20u1 down
# ip tuntap add dev tap0 mode tap user $(whoami)
# ip link add br0 type bridge
# ip link set enp0s20u1 master br0
# ip link set tap0 master br0
# ip link set enp0s20u1 up
# ip link set tap0 up
# ip link set br0 up
```

A quick overview of the bridge.

```
# brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.0050b609a5d1       no              enp0s20u1
                                                        tap0
```

Start a dhcp client on the bridge:

```
# dhcpcd br0
```

Then you can plug the tap interface (tap0) to the android emulator via -qemu options when you launch the emulator.

```
./opt/android-sdk/emulator/emulator \
  -avd android_25_x86 \
  -verbose -no-window \
  -qemu \
  -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=hn0,mac=52:55:00:d1:55:51 \
  -netdev tap,id=hn0,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no
```

Normaly a new eth1 interface is present in the android emulator. And you can run the dhcpclient binary if it present or configure static route to your network, then it work.

```
generic_x86:/ # ping -c 1 -I eth1 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 192.168.1.60 eth1: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=17.1 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 17.160/17.160/17.160/0.000 ms
```

But I have some issues to ping the emulator from the outside or route all the traffic in the emulator to the host network, see my other post.

[Connect android emulator to lan](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/191522/connect-android-emulator-to-lan)

Comment: I get `RTNETLINK answers: Device or resource busy` when I call `ip link set enp0s20u1 master br0`